# error:in m/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS6.0.sdk/usr/lib/crt1.3.1.o, file is universal but does not contain a(n) armv6 slice for architecture armv6

Tags: ios4, xcode4, ios6

I am getting above error in xcode. The detail error is

> ld: in
>   /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS6.0.sdk/usr/lib/crt1.3.1.o,
>   file is universal but does not contain a(n) armv6 slice for
>   architecture armv6 collect2: ld returned 1 exit status Command
>   /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/llvm-gcc-4.2
>   failed with exit code 1

But there is a situation which i want to explain. My iphone device which was 3GS, by mistake we upgraded it to 6.0. Previously it was iOS 4.3. Now we are trying to downgrade but unable to that. We have a application which we need to run on this device. So i downloaded latest xcode 4.5. and i copied iOS 6 sdk in my current sdk. Xocde version is 4.0. After that i tried to compile the application for device, and i am getting above error. I know the problem is coming because of iOS sdk 6.0. But i don't getting solution. Anybody can help please.This link which i have used to copy iOS 6 sdk in current xcode is this

```
http://iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/100229-snow-leopard-sdk-5-1-a.html
```

Answer (score 2):

setting YES to architecture->Build active architecture only in build setting has solved my problem. :)
I hope this will not create a new issue.